# php echo string together with variable not working

Tags: php, echo

I've made a simple php service test (I call it via jquery):

Value in "searchterm" is e.g. "11" or "test" etc.

This returns without problem:

```
<?php

$variable = $_POST["searchterm"];
echo $variable;

?>
```

This do not work at all (does not return).

```
<?php

$variable = $_POST["searchterm"];
echo "Test ".$variable;

?>
```

I feel really stupid but I don't get why the second one is not working... Haven't I done this kind of concatenation a thousand times before??

To give some more information:

This is how I call the php file:

```
    function startSearch(){
        var searchValue = $('#searchInput').val();

        $.post('./ifsearch-test.php',
            {searchterm: searchValue},
            function(data,status){
                showSearchResult(data);
        });

        $('#searchInput').val('');
    }
```

Comment: is it because you need a space between your period? `echo "Test " . $variable;`

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the `$_POST` variable? For me, it works http://pastebin.com/HBxMsVyZ

Comment: @indubitablee, That is not correct. No space is needed.

Comment: @Hamburger, tell us what result you get. "This do not work at all" is not of any help!

Comment: @theFX, yes. if I remove the string from the echo statement, it works for me, too...

Comment: Check if the name attribute of the input field in the Form matches with the $_POST['attributename'];

Comment: @crafter, I appologize. I have edited the question accordingly: "This do not work at all >>>>(does not return).<<<<". Plz consider also the added code who calls the php file...

Comment: @HamburgerTS can you not turn error reporting on?

Comment: `Does not return` sounds to me like your web server hangs - but I don't think that's what you mean. Have you monitored your http requests in your web browser to see what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

So... this is really, really awkward...

I find out that all of it DO return. So I just wasted everybody's time with this...

To explain:

I use this function to handle the returned value:

```
    function showSearchResult(result) {
        result = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
        $('#searchView').html(result);
    }
```

He get an exception at

```
jQuery.parseJSON(result)
```

if I return

```
echo "Test ".$variable;
```

Of course I should have seen this via debugging but I used a breakpoint in the line after that and had the impression it does not return at all.

I'm so sorry. I'm a complete idiot!

However: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR TIME AND HELP NONETHELESS!!